# asp.net core fileprovider get all drives

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I would like to get all drives with the IFileProvider (PhysicalFileProvider) in asp.net core 2.0.

Is there a extra using which have to get? Or has anybody an example for this?

regards
Chris

Comment: check my answer if you are looking for an example

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;` in your REST API controller and startup file to use the `PhysicalFileProvider` class that implements the `IFileProvider` interface. You can use `GetDirectoryContents()` method to iterate the files.

Check the below links for a detail example to get files from a root directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/file-providers-in-asp-net-core/

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1204104/ASP-NET-Core-File-Providers

Comment: I know this but apparently there is no way to access a harddrive. Only a Directory.

Answer (score 1):

`IFileProvider` assumes you start from a single root and as far as I know .Net core does not provide a direct way to group all drives under a single root directory.

`PhysicalFileProvider` by itself certainly won't work for the same reason.

Therefore, if possible, I would simply use `System.IO.DriveInfo` to get the drive list. 
If testability is what you need, then I'd wrap it inside a custom class and define an interface for it, something in the sense of:

```
interface IDriveInfo
{
    string[] GetDrives();
}
```

But if, due to existing abstractions or so on, you really need to use `IFileProvider`, 
you can use `CompositeFileProvider` in combination with `System.IO.DriveInfo` to achieve what you want as follows:

```
public IFileProvider GetFileProvider()
{
    var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    List<IFileProvider> fileProviders = new List<IFileProvider>();
    foreach(var drive in drives)
    {
        if (drive.IsReady)
        {
            fileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(drive.RootDirectory.ToString()));
        }
    }
    return new CompositeFileProvider(fileProviders.ToArray());
}
```

This still will not give you a list of drives, but you could iterate over the result of `GetDirectoryContents` to create a list of drives manually.

```
HashSet<string> drives = new HashSet<string>();
var fp = GetFileProvider();
foreach (var fileInfo in fp.GetDirectoryContents(""))
{
    var pos = fileInfo.PhysicalPath.IndexOf(':');
    var driveLetter =  fileInfo.PhysicalPath.Substring(0, pos+1);
    drives.Add(driveLetter);
}
```

I tested this on .Net CORE 3.0, but according to the documentation it should work the same for version 2.0:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.compositefileprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.0